# aws rds store longtext issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

Hi I try to store in my maria DB hosted on aws rds values with typ longtext. Its html stuff.

Single words are stored. But full html pages not. What prameter size do I have to change to store longtext?

already increased max_allowed_packagesize.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

The HTML is about 14k lines if I store it in a .txt file its about 1MB

the create table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ResultCrawlerFK
(
  resultCrawlerFKId bigint(255) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  resultId bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  tagId bigint(255),
  classId bigint(255),
  idId bigint(255),
  changeDetected BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  content  LONGTEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (resultCrawlerFKId),
  constraint FOREIGN KEY (resultId) REFERENCES ResultsCrawler (resultId),
  constraint FOREIGN KEY (tagId) REFERENCES Tags (tagId),
  constraint FOREIGN KEY (classId) REFERENCES ClassesCrawler (classId),
  constraint FOREIGN KEY (idId) REFERENCES IdsCrawler (idId)

);
```

and the insert like this:

https://gist.github.com/holzfelix/591b02c7f77d65a8725e4321e80980dc

Comment: Show us the SQL.  How long is the HTML?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Is it all English?  Provide other details.

Comment: @RickJames added above. The Language is english/german/french

Comment: Are those long strings truncated to one word?